# Prove the following propositions for matrices are true or false.

Tags: linear-algebra

Assume you have an $m \times n$ matrix $A$.

1. If the reduced row echelon form of $A$ has a zero row, then $m \geq n$.
2. If $m = n$ and the reduced row echelon form of $A$ has a column of $0$'s, the the reduced row echelon form of $A$ has a row of $0$'s.
3. If $m = n$ and the reduced row echelon form of $A$ has a row of $0$'s, the the reduced row echelon form of $A$ has a column of $0$'s.

I can easily come up with a counterexample for statement 1, so it should be false.
The below matrix should be enough to prove this false.

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
Here the number of columns $n$ are more than the number of rows $m$.

However I'm unsure if statements 2 or 3 are proven false as easily.

Comment: Your counterexample doesn't make sense -- how $n = 2$ is "more than'' $m = 4$?

Comment: if your matrix is $m \times n$ you have $m$ rows and $n$ columns.

Answer (score 1):

Statement 1 is false. As you may have intended (but you mistyped somehow), try
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}
with $m = 2$ and $n = 4$, and its second row is all zeros.

Statement 3 is false, consider
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0  
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Statement 2 is true. If all rows of $A$'s reduced echelon form are non-zero, then $\text{rank}(A) = m = n$. On the other hand, if a column of $A$ is all zero, this would lead to $\text{rank}(A) < n$, contradiction. Therefore, there must be a row of $A$ consists of all $0$s.